# Example that in general $|abc|\neq |cba|$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, examples-counterexamples

I tried to provide an example of group elements $a,b,c$ that shows that in general  $|abc|\neq |cba|$.

> Please could you tell me if my example is correct?

Let $G$ be the dihedral group $D_6$ (the symmetries of a hexagon). Let us label the axes of symmetry with numbers $1$ to $6$ and call the corresponding reflections $F_1$ to $F_6$.

Now consider two "adjacent" reflections $F_1$ and $F_2$. Then

$$ F_1 F_2$$

is rotation clockwise by $120$ degrees and

$$ F_2 F_1$$

is roation by $120$ degrees counterclockwise.

Let $R$ be rotation by $120$ degrees counterclockwise. Then

$$ R F_1 F_2 = e$$

has order $1$ but

$$ F_2 F_1 R$$

is rotation by $240$ counterclockwise which has order not equal to $1$.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, cr001 and Crostful!

Answer (score 2):

Take G to be any group, let x,y be elements of G and observe that the commutator
[x,y] = x'y'xy (here x' denotes the inverse of x in G) can be written as a product abc such that cba=1. Indeed, just take a=x', b=y'x and c=y.

Now if x,y don't commute you get that abc is nontrivial, while cba is trivial and presto: you have infinitely many easy examples.

N.B. This trick also shows that in any group G, if a finite product of elements is trivial, then the product of the same elements in reverse order belongs to the derived subgroup G'.

Also: the elements of G' are those finite products of elements in G whose corresponding product in reverse order is the identity.

Hope this helps.